# Get div value by id - Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, html

I'm trying to get the value of my div into Javascript. It's a Drupal website and I want to convert currencies and displaying them in a javascript popup.

So far I have this:

```
<?php 
        print "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        $rate=currency_api_convert("HKD", "CNY");
        print "exchangerate = ".$rate["value"].";";

        print "var $displaycur = getElementById('record-price');";
        print "$displaycur;";

        print "</script>";
?>
```

And all I get in my browers is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        exchangerate = 0.8406;var  = getElementById('record-price');;
</script>
```

Although I know the reason why it's displayed like this, I still don't know how to get the ID of the div in a proper variable.
Any ideas? Should I use innerHTML?

**UPDATE:**
A part of the source files:
*page.tpl.php*

```
<?php
// $Id: page.tpl.php,v 1.18.2.1 2009/04/30 00:13:31 goba Exp $
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir ?>">
  <head>
    <?php print $head ?>
    <title><?php print $head_title ?></title>
    <?php print $styles ?>
    <?php print $scripts ?>
    <?php 
        // lets get the exchange rate from HKD to RMB, with the help of yahoo finance api and the currency api module
        // we pass the value to javascript, the tooltip will handle the rest
        print "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        $rate=currency_api_convert("HKD", "CNY");
        print "exchangerate = ".$rate["value"].";";
        print "</script>";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showCurrency() {
            alert('$rate');
        }
    </script>
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
      <?php print phptemplate_get_ie_styles(); ?>
    <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE 6]>
            <style type="text/css">
                .fg-menu-ipod .fg-menu li { width: 95%; }
                .fg-menu-ipod .ui-widget-content { border:0; }
                .views-field-field-performer-value { margin-left:-150px;}
                .views-field-field-instruments-value { margin-left:-150px;}
                .coda-nav{display:block; position:absolute; width:400px;height:20px;top:260px;right:100px;z-index:125421;}  </style>
        <![endif]-->


  </head>
  <body<?php print phptemplate_body_class($left, $right); ?>>
```

And the *node-record.tpl.php*:

```
print '<div id="part1-right-line3">';   
    print '<div id="record-price">';                                                        
    print uc_currency_format($node->sell_price);
    print '</div>';                     
    print '</div>'; 
    print '<div id="part1-right-line4">';   
    print '<div id="add-to-cart">';     
    print drupal_get_form('uc_product_add_to_cart_form_'. $node->nid, $node);
    print '</div>'; 
    print '</div>';
    print '</div>';
```

And here is the output:
[image]
Please tell me if you need more, cause there is :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm extremely confused by this: `var = getElementById('record-price');;`

Comment: Thanks for you comments, I want to place the div value inside a variable, so I can use this to convert the currency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
   print "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
   $rate=currency_api_convert("HKD", "CNY");
   print "exchangerate = ".$rate["value"].";\n";
   print "var displaycur = document.getElementById('record-price');\n";
   print "alert(displaycur.innerHTML);\n";
   print "</script>\n";
?>
```

I guess **'record-price'** is ID of your DIV... so `displaycur.innerHTML` will have everything between `<div>` and `</div>`.

---

**EDIT:**

```
function showCurrency() {
  alert(document.getElementById('record-price').innerHTML);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, 'record-price' is indeed the ID of the DIV.
When I replaced my code with yours, I get a `missing variable name` error:

Comment: @Michiel - can I see complete output online?

Comment: @Michiel - Maybe you can post source in your original question? I'm very curious about this.

Comment: Sweet, You can find it [here](http://pentatone.pentatone.them.pro/toccata-200-years-german-organ-music) and I'll add the code in my original question!

Comment: @Michiel - Now it reads DIV's value correctly. Remove that F*** comment, please :)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, sorry can't edit it anymore. Thank you again! I can't multiply it or anything like that, correct? It's just a string?

Comment: @Michiel - incorrect... search Google for javascript functions to cut-off string part "HKD" so you'll get clear float number and you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined `$displaycur` in your PHP code? Also, it should be `document.getElementById`.

**Update:** All you need from PHP is the exchange rate. You can do everything else in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var exchangerate = <?php echo currency_api_convert("HKD", "CNY"); ?>;
var div = document.getElementById('record-price');
var price = parseInt(div.innerHTML);

// convert and display
alert(price * exchangerate);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! No, I haven't defined it in my PHP code before. Should I do it inside the javascript?

Comment: @Michiel: PHP considers `$displaycur` to be a variable and substitutes its value in the output. If this wasn't intended, you should remove or escape the `$` sign.

Comment: I just want to place the value of the div inside a variable so I can convert it. But since it's a Drupal (php), I have to do it like this, no?

Comment: @casablance, thanks for you answer, but I keep getting errors (`div is null`-error). 
And in my code I'm getting `var exchangerate = Array`

Comment: @casablanca, `currency_api_convert()` returns array... it should be arrays element ["value"]. I guess thats why $rate["value"] stands for

Comment: @Michiel, well, something is wrong with your DIV then; `'div is null'` error!? Can you see that DIV in output source? In, my example, you've got `'missing variable name'` error, so I guess DIV is a problem.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, the output source of the div: `<div id="record-price">125.00HKD</div>`

Comment: @Michiel, when I put this DIV in front of my example, it alerts message **"125.00HKD"** (without quotes), so I think that problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, aarh crap... F*** Drupal nodes and pages! Ok, I'll take a look to something else. Thanks for the answers and comments!

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, this is the code of the div, don't know if you can do something with it?print `'print '<div id="record-price">';              
 print uc_currency_format($node->sell_price);
 print '</div>';`